# How I can find on console in GIT hash of commit on which two branches bagan to differ?

Tags: git, version-control, logging, workflow

I have a branch foo and branch master

I want to find out when branch foo began to differ from master

I'm trying it with

```
git log origin/master..origin/foo
```

And then I look at the oldest commit

What is the better approach ?

Comment: thx, you're right, was not sure how to ask about it / search this term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is most probably `git merge-base`.